# How to increase speed between changing photos in Photos/iPhoto?

Tags: photos.app

I am trying to view through the photos, but the process is painfully slow. How do you increase the speed of transition or remove the transition  altogether so that when you press arrow keys or do three finger swipe the change is instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my question was not fully researched.
Swipe takes some transition time which I do not know how to modify but using arrow keys gives instantaneous transition.